# how to save pi to database or disk, then can query in 10 seconds?

Tags: python

pi has been calculated to 31.4 trillion bits(https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/calculating-31-4-trillion-digits-of-archimedes-constant-on-google-cloud). I want to store this data in a database or hard disk, and then query and use it. I hope that the query time will be within 10 seconds. What solution should I use?

If a table stores 5 million rows of data, each row of data stores 500 numbers, and a table can store 2.5 billion digits, a total of 12,000 tables are needed.

And a table requires 1182.8 GB of storage space, all of which require 13.5 PB of storage space, so the query will be very slow.

[update]

1. I want to use python
2. I want to query all occurrences of a string of numbers in pi
3. If 10 seconds is not possible, it is acceptable to get the result within one minute

Comment: nice though experiment the max size if databases you find here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems#Limits  you willm need a database with 2 columns first position and second number, you don't need to store them all in one table, you can use partitions. stuill i don't think that rdms actually can hold that much. And index on position, so you can get quite quickm to the nth position, or find three  numbers in a row for example, but i still doubt that is enough for  10 seconds.even with a hash as index

Comment: To answer your question, it depends on what query you're doing.  Let's assume 16 bits per digit or 2 trillion digits.  When would you ever need to retrieve all 2 trillion digits?  A  WQUXGA monitor displays 3840 x 2400 pixels, which roughly translates into a maximum of around 230,000 digits.  If you tried to print all 2 trillion digits, you would still retrieve a page at a time.

Comment: No database or any other type of software can make it possible to read 13 petabytes from disk in less than 10 seconds. There are physical limitations involved.

Comment: @nbk - In MySQL, for a single table:  MyISAM is limited to 2^56 bytes; InnoDB, to 2^61 bytes (using partitioning).  That is more than the 2^45 required for pi.  All of these assume no compression.  Disk size and OS filesystem limits -- I don't have those numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's digits, not bits.

31.4 trillion digits, stored in a simple way would take 31.4 TB (TB = trillion *bytes*) of disk space.

Compress it, and you can squeeze it into about 10TB, but no tighter.  "Information theory" says that's the limit."

No disk, not even SSD or the fastest flash drive can load even 1TB into RAM in 10 seconds.  If you wanted all 31.4TB in RAM, I don't think you can build a machine with anywhere near that much RAM.

There is some overhead when putting data into a database.  2x-3x is a typical number.  So 31.4TB might become 90TB of disk.  Or 30TB compressed.  Less than a Petabyte.

If you want to load it in pieces, we can discuss further.  I might suggest an uncompressed text file if you can figure out how to get a disk that holds that much.  Then use fopen, fseek, read to fetch an arbitrary chunk.  Any chunk would have very low overhead to "seek", then a "read" time proportional to the number of bytes being read.

What computer languages do you program in?

More importantly, what will you do with the data?

Comment: @artwl - What's the fastest disk drive in the world?  You want 10 seconds.  Are you willing to spend several weeks of preprocessing of the data so that an arbitrary substring can be found in 10 seconds?